# add data environment in visual basic 6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have a problem with visual basic 6 when I try to add data environment that shows me this problem https://ufile.io/wckxn
Note:
The data environment did not appear to me until I used this code
register "C:\Program Files\Common Files\DESIGNER\msde.dll" in CMD
Then I had the previous problem.
please help me!!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your issues are.  The CLSID in your screen print is associated with C:\Program Files\Common Files\designer\MSDERUN.DLL, not msde.dll, so try registering (regsvr32.exe) msderun.dll to resolve the error in your screen pic.

Comment: You can paste that image directly into your question.